# "But the point is probably moot." Is it arguable or irrelevant?

Tags: meaning, etymology

(Not really answered [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127395/what-does-the-the-point-is-moot-in-the-context-mean).)
See also [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298089/dangerously-closely-antonyms) - I think I found a self-antonym.
I took up some research after hearing "Jessie's Girl", and I think the following etymology developments hold:

- "Moot" initially meant "debatable", also "uncertain".
- Since points can be debated to death and uncertain points practically are, eh, pointless, the meaning also took up the sense "irrelevant".
- For exact this reason, I expect the shift of meaning to have happened in the Internet age.
- Nowadays "moot" is almost always used in the second sense.

But I'm a German and thus have not much access to "living" English. Thus, please confirm or deny my educated guesses, preferrably with references.

Comment: It's true that sometimes ***moot*** means "arguable" (not so often nowadays, frankly). But I suggest that whenever it's qualified as ***probably** moot*, it's practically 100% certain the intended meaning is "irrelevant".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "the point is moot " in the context mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127395/what-does-the-the-point-is-moot-in-the-context-mean)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because the OP links that proposed dupe question first thing in this question, saying it's "not really answered" there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting *Guardian* article "The meaning of ‘moot’ is a moot point – whichever variety of English you speak"

> moot remains a lovely and versatile word, equally at home as noun,
> adjective or verb – and **with contrasting meanings, depending on which
> side of the Atlantic you are using it**.

> a moot point, initially a legal issue, became used more widely to mean
> one that was open to argument, debatable or uncertain. The author
> Gerald Durrell used it in this sense when he wrote: “Whether he could
> have bitten us successfully ... was rather a moot point, but it was
> not the sort of experiment I cared to make.”

> Today, **I think most British English speakers would use moot in this
> sense**, or as a verb to mean proposed (“Banking: plan mooted for merger
> of trade associations” ran a typical headline this week). **It’s a
> different story in the United States**, where since the 19th century a
> moot point has been one that is at best academic and at worst
> irrelevant.

[Mind your language - moot point (The Guardian)](https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2015/jan/16/mind-your-language-moot-point)

Comment: THX, that was exactly the kind of primary source I hoped to get. (E.g. that it is also an UK/US issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Have often wondered about use of phrase 'moot point'. There seems to be a split
between American English and the UK version. Have only heard it used in its 'no longer relevant/worth discussing' sense in the States, whereas in the UK it means precisely the opposite. I think author JRR Tolkien would side with the UK incarnation since he refers to a meeting of Ents (giant trees) as an Ent Moot.